# MongoDriver c# Filter by month Name from a Date Field

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Requirement : Need to filter the mongo documents by month (Data is stored in mongo as date time)

Code used :  `var expenseMonthFilter = Builders<MyDocument>.Filter.Eq(i => i.ExpenseDate.Month, 12);`

Exception Getting :`Unable to determine the serialization information for i => i.ExpenseDate.Month.`

[image: Mongo Data Image]

Comment: Do you want to retrieve all the docs of a certain month (e.g. January of 2021) or all the docs of Januaries in various years?

Comment: Hi @Markus All the records by selected month (current year)

Comment: anything beyond basic queries in mongo generally requires an aggregate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When selecting all the document of a month, the condition needs to retrieve all documents that have a ExpenseDate that is greather than or equal to the start date of the month and less than the start date of the following month, like so:

```
var startOfMonth = new DateTime(selectedYear, selectedMonth, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var startOfNextMonth = startOfMonth.AddMonths(1);
var bldr = Builders<MyDocument>.Filter;
var expenseMonthFilter = bldr.And(
    bldr.Gte(x => x.ExpenseDate, startOfMonth), 
    bldr.Lt(x => x.ExpenseDate, startOfNextMonth));
```

Please not that in the sample above, selectedYear stands for the year, selectedMonth for the month that the data should be retrieved for.

Answer (score 1):

the default mongo date is just a number not a date, you have to apply external transformations to convert it to a date, to do this you need to use an aggregation to transform the data before you query it

one option is to use a Grouping to preselect the data ie

```
PipelineDefinition<BsonDocument, BsonDocument> pipeline = new BsonDocument[]
{
    new BsonDocument("$group", new BsonDocument()
            .Add("_id", new BsonDocument()
                    .Add("month", new BsonDocument()
                            .Add("$month", "$yourDateField")
                    )
            )
            .Add("data", new BsonDocument()
                    .Add("$addToSet", "$$ROOT")
            )), 
    new BsonDocument("$match", new BsonDocument()
            .Add("_id.month", 6.0))
};
```

if you just want to group the data by month then you wouldn't need the match stage each group would be in the form of

```
_id.nonth:int,
data:<collection of base docs that are in that month>
```

another option would be to reproject each document before matching

```
PipelineDefinition<BsonDocument, BsonDocument> pipeline = new BsonDocument[]
{
    new BsonDocument("$project", new BsonDocument()
            .Add("month", new BsonDocument()
                    .Add("$month", "$yourDateField")
            )
            .Add("root", "$$ROOT")), 
    new BsonDocument("$match", new BsonDocument()
            .Add("month", 6.0))
};
```

either of these would then be called by

```
var cursor = await collection.AggregateAsync(pipeline, options)
```

if you want to include the years that would be a simple call to the $year function like i have the $month function